# ¿Cómo solucionar Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() al mostrar datos de una tabla?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, crud

Tengo una página llamada `categories`, en donde hay una lista de categorías que el usuario va creando, y estas se van agregando a una tabla llamada `categories` que se compone únicamente de dos columnas (`id` y `name`).

Lo que quisiera hacer es que el usuario pueda actualizar el nombre de las categorías, sin embargo y debido a mi falta de conocimiento en PHP, no lo he logrado. Al darle actualizar lanza este error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\menu\admin\actualizar->categoria.php on line 25
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\menu\admin\actualizar-categoria.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\menu\admin\actualizar-categoria.php on line 25

Aquí el código que da el error:

```
<?php

    require 'database.php';

    if(!empty($_GET['id'])) 
    {
        $id = checkInput($_GET['id']);
    }

    $nameError = "";

    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    {
        $name = checkInput($_POST['name']);
        $isSuccess  = true;
       
        if(empty($name)) 
        {
            $nameError = 'Este campo no puede estar vacío';
            $isSuccess = false;
        }
        else
        {
        $statement = $db->prepare(" UPDATE categories  set name = ? WHERE id = ?");
        $statement->execute(array($name,$id));
        
        }
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: categorias.php");
        }

    else 
    {
        $db = Database::connect();
        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories where id = ?");
        $statement->execute(array($id));
        $categories = $statement->fetch();
        $name       = $categories['name'];
        Database::disconnect();
    }

    function checkInput($data) 
    {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }

?>
```

Comment: que script usas para la conexion a la base de datos no se que ejecuta fetch; PDO o mysqli???

Comment: segun veo el warning tiene que ver con la variable "db" sabes que variable es esa ???

Comment: En este enlace puse el codigo , en el html esta la pagina actualizar.php y en el css coloque el código de conexión de la db https://codepen.io/klish/pen/jOVmQZY

Answer (score 0):

Según veo tu problema está en este fragmento de codigo:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{
    $name = checkInput($_POST['name']);
    $isSuccess  = true;
   
    if(empty($name)) 
    {
        $nameError = 'Este campo no puede estar vacío';
        $isSuccess = false;
    }
    else
    {
    // AQUI EL PROBLEMA, LA VARIABLE $DB NO ESTA DEFINIDA POR ENDE NO SE 
    // PUEDE LLAMAR AL METODO PREPARE
    $statement = $db->prepare(" UPDATE categories  set name = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $statement->execute(array($name,$id));
    
    }
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: categorias.php");
    }
```

Y esto según veo es porque la variable `$db` no esta definida aun por ende no se puede llamar al método `prepare()`, por otra parte, para asignar parámetros, que según veo estas ocupando PDO, debes utilizar **`$statement->bindParam(numParametro, variable)`**, por ejemplo yo lo haría así:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{
    $name = checkInput($_POST['name']);
    $isSuccess  = true;
   
    if(empty($name)) 
    {
        $nameError = 'Este campo no puede estar vacío';
        $isSuccess = false;
    }
    else
    {
    $db = Database::connect();
    $statement = $db->prepare(" UPDATE categories  set name = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $statement->bindParam(1, $name);
    $statement->bindParam(2, $id);
    $statement->execute();
    }
        //CERRAR CONEXION
        $db = null;
        $statement = null;
        header("Location: categorias.php");
    }
```

Asimismo, es aconsejable meter eso dentro de un **try-catch**, de esta manera puedes manejar las excepciones que te lance el código.

> **PD:** Si hay algún problema con el código o errores de sintaxis corregirme ya que la solución la he planteado según mis conocimiento de php, base de datos que he obtenido hasta el momento, saludos!

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias Francisco, funciono exelente